# Hide a menu on posts

Tags: menus

Is it possible to not have a menu on post pages. I think it would be something like "if page show menu, if post don't show menu" but I'm not sure how to put that into PHP.

Thanks

Comment: can you tell me which menu you want to hide `wp_nav_menu();` or your custom menu?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_single()) {
 // DONT SHOW MENUS
}
```

you may pass a post id for any specific post for eg -

```
if (is_single('4')) {
     // DONT SHOW MENUS
    }
```

will execute on post with id = 4 . hope it helps

Comment: prince what is `if_single()` it's `is_single()` or use `if (is_single()) { // some code }`

Comment: oops i made mistake there thankyou for pointing out..

Comment: Thanks, I understand it but I'm not sure how to write the don't show part?
I have  `<nav><?php categories() ?></nav>`

Comment: if (!is_single()) {
 // show menus here.ie you wp_nav_menu() funtion...simple ?
}

Comment: Ah, yes I think I have it working now I went with: 
`<?php if( (is_single()) ||  (is_page('about')) ||  (is_page('contact') )) { ?>
    <style type="">
        .cat_nav_wrap { display: none; }
    </style>
    <?php } ?>`

Answer (score 1):

While you can use CSS to hide elements, I don't think it's ideal, especially for something like a menu. In effect, that element and its queries will still run and load (and therefore affect your page's speed), only to be hidden by the CSS.

I would recommend, instead, either editing your theme's `header.php` or creating a child theme with a new `header.php` file that conditionally loads the menu on pages that aren't `single.php`. In the TwentyThirteen theme, fr'ex, you would use the following in your `header.php` file:

```
  <?php if (is_singular()) :
        // DO NOTHING
  else : ?>
           <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
              <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                 <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h3>
                 <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
                 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
                 <?php get_search_form(); ?>
              </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
           </div><!-- #navbar -->
  <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for doing that. Your right that seems like a much better approach. Thank you.